# Is it allowed to use Like button for another page?

Tags: url

According [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203164/facebook-like-button-which-likes-another-page-url) it is possible to place Like button on some page, while the like button gives "like" to another page. But is it allowed officially? 
Aren't there any sanctions from Facebook if I like page from another page?

On [documentation page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button) for Like button, there is mentioned that I can set "href" parameter, for example  "href" parameter can be set to my Facebook fan page. But there is no mention that I can use this parameter widely for any page. Can I think, that when it is not forbidden, it is as allowed?

I would need to use Like button, so users likes another page (on the same domain) then the current URL.

Answer (score 1):

You might want the `href` to point to the root of your website instead of the current page. That is not forbidden. But, I am not sure that you could point to another website's page.

And if you can, this would be equivalent to misleading a user in having him believe that he/she liked the page he/she clicked on, when in fact he liked another page. If Facebook finds about it, you would deserve a penalty. You have the right to use a knife to eat, not to murder. Gotta be responsible.

Likes have little to no direct impact on ranking, so I don't see the purpose of fiddling with this feature, especially if you have SEO in mind.

Comment: Don't forget to approve the answer if you like it, thanks!